# Writing tensor to a file in a visually readable manner

Tags: python, file-io, pytorch, tensor, file-writing

In pytorch, I want to write a tensor to a file and visually read the file contents. For example, consider T = torch.tensor([3,4,5,6]). I want to write the tensor T to a file, say file_T.txt, and want to visually read the contents of the file_T.txt, which will be 3,4,5 and 6. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('my_file.txt', torch.Tensor([3,4,5,6]).numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.savetxt()` but it won't work if your tensor's dimensions are higher than 2. Moreover, this method could be used only if your tensor is on a CPU.